# How to unify the number of non-NA cells in raster stack?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have raster files that have the same resolution and extent but differ in the number of NA. I want to unify the number of NA between all of them. Is it possible to do it by considering a cell as non-NA if it's not NA in all the raster files?

Here an example :

```
   library(raster)
library(terra)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r1 <- raster(f)
r2 <- calc(r1, fun=function(x){ x[x < 500] <- NA; return(x)} )
r1 <- calc(r1, fun=function(x){ x[x > 1200] <- NA; return(x)} )
raste <-  rast(r1)
rNA <- terra:: global(!(is.na(raste)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
print(paste0("Non-NA of r1", rNA))
raste <-  rast(r2)
rNA <- terra:: global(!(is.na(raste)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
print(paste0("Non-NA of r2", rNA))
```

I want both `r1` and `r2` to have the same number of non-NA cells. I have more than two rasters, so I wonder if I can do it for a large number of files.

Comment: Could you give an example dataset and the expected output?

Comment: @slamballais I updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing to use raster and terra together, so I will just use `terra` (but you can do the same with `raster`, using `stack` in stead of `c` and `cellStats` in stead of `global`.

Your example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- rast(f)
r1 <- clamp(r, upper=1200, values=FALSE)
r2 <- clamp(r, lower=500, values=FALSE)

global(!(is.na(r1)), sum)
#       sum
#lyr.1 3145
global(!(is.na(r2)), sum)
#      sum
#lyr.1 802
```

Solution:

```
r <- c(r1, r2)
names(r) <- c("r1", "r2")

m <- any(is.na(r))
x <- mask(r, m, maskvalue=1)

global(!(is.na(x)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
#   sum
#r1 769
#r2 769
```

I like the use of `any(is.na())` because it makes clear what the intent is.

But you could combine the layers in one of many other ways. As long as you do not use `na.rm=TRUE` the cells with an `NA` in one of the layers will be `NA` in the output. For example with `sum`, `diff`, `prod`, `mean` or `app`.

```
m <- sum(r)
x <- mask(r, m)
global(!(is.na(x)), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot but can you explain to me why you chose the argument maskvalue=1 ?

Comment: I use a `0/1` (`FALSE/TRUE`) layer to `mask` cells where the condition (`any(is.na(x))`  is `TRUE`, hence the use of `maskvalue=1` instead of the default `NA`. `maskvalue=TRUE` also works.